# Read the custom field and split the text. Read the last value from array

Tags: apex, trigger

**Create a new before insert trigger to do below action:​

Read ‘Event Name’ field and split the text based on ‘(‘ character. Read the last value of array then remove ‘)’ from it.**​

I have tried this so far. I am not sure where it is correct or not.

```
trigger myTrigger on Timecard__c (before insert) 
 {
   for (Timecard__c timeCard : Trigger.new) 
   {
      string one = timeCard.Event_Name__C;
      String[] bits = one.split("(");
      String lastOne = bits[bits.length-1];
  }
}
```

Can you please help me how to Read the last value of array then remove ‘)’ from it.​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use substringBetween:

```
String one = timeCard.Event_Name__c.substringBetween('(',')');
```

Comment: Then how can we get last value of array?

Comment: @Pooh No split, no array, just use the method designed for the purpose you're looking for.